# Arraylist in driver class not resolved to variable

Tags: java, arraylist, driver

Alright, so in my driver class, I want to call my arraylist from another class and print it out. However, when I attempt to call the method, it says that the variable cannot be resolved to a variable. Does anyone have any idea how I can get it "to be resolved".

Here's my code:

Driver:

```
public static void showing(){
        OtherClass.initializeStrings();
        System.out.println(OtherClass.showLists(mouseTypes));
    }
```

Other Class:

```
       static ArrayList <String> mouseTypes;
            public static void initializeStrings(){ //initialize the strings outside the main 
                     Strings = new ArrayList <String>(); 
                        Strings.add("goodbye");
                        Strings.add("hello");
                        Strings.add("hi");
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            OtherClass.initializeStrings();
            Driver.showing();
        }
public static void showLists(ArrayList list){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the Arraylist named mouseTypes? Or what is this Strings  you are adding  stuff to?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.showLists(OtherClass.mouseTypes)`.

However, that breaks both the Single Responsibility Principle, and Encapsulation. Fix it.

Also, you have done a very bad copy-paste job, you have two `main` methods...